# Chrome 57: Menu, Tab, Bookmark fonts very large

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility

I have updated my google-chrome to version 57 , after that menu font size and tabs font size and bookmark bar font size , are very large. and I hate that. So I try to fix it,but I can't.
How I fix it?

[image]

Comment: What OS are you using?